# Making a for next loop

Tags: excel, vba

**how do we repair the program? This  program stop working with error invalid Next control variable reference on lin Next n.**

```
Sub RemoveRows5()
     ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.ClearFormats
    Dim n As Long
    n = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  
For i = n To 1 Step -1
 
        If InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(n, 1).Text, "<>", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(n, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
Next i
    End Sub**
```

Comment: The correct syntax would be `For i = n To 1 Step -1`

Comment: Note that `Range("A" & Rows.Count)` is a shortcut to `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count)` which may of may not refer to the same worksheet as  `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet` .  If `ThisWorkbook` (ie the workbook containing the code) is _not_ the Active Workbook, then these two lines will refer to different worksheets.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect, your code should be:

```
Sub RemoveRows5()

ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.ClearFormats
Dim n As Long, i As Long
n = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  
For i = n To 1 Step -1
    If InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Text, "<>", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Note that the correct syntax for a loop is `For x = i To j Step k`, where `x` is a numeric variable that will store an value from `i` to `j` with a step size of `k`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below:

```
Sub RemoveRows5()
    
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    
    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

        .Cells.ClearFormats

        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
          
        For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
            If InStr(1, .Cells(i, 1).Text, "<>", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                .Row(i).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next i
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```